# How do I configure FetchClient to use a non-default api when using Aurelia Auth

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-auth

I'm setting up aurelia-auth and configured endpoints for my authorization server and a protected api:

```
  aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-api', configure => {
configure
  .registerEndpoint('auth', 'http://localhost:5000/')
  .registerEndpoint('api', 'http://localhost:5006')}
```

When I want to fetch data I inject the AuthService into my module and then call

```
this.authService.config.client.client.fetch('StaticData/offices')
```

but this calls against the `auth` endpoint not the `api` one, how do I tell the fetch client to use the non-default endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was heading down the wrong path, you use the configuration object off `aurelia-api` to get an endpoint you can then call:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Config } from 'aurelia-api'


@inject (Config)
export class Locations {
    constructor (private apiEndpointConfig: Config)
    {}
    dataItems;
    hasItems: boolean;

   created(){

    var api =  this.apiEndpointConfig.getEndpoint('api');
    api.client.fetch('StaticData/offices')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(response=> 
    {
        this.dataItems=response;
        this.hasItems=true;
    });
 }
```

}